# Как удалить первый символ в строке с replace()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Функция `replace()` принимает в моём случае следующие аргументы:
`str.replace(old, new)`, где `old` это элемент в строке, который нужно заменить, а `new` это элемент на который мы заменим.

Нужно заменить первую букву в `value`, то есть "i". Но при работе с replace он заменяет ВСЕ символы (т.е. "i"):

```
value = "interesting"
value.replace("i", "")
print(value)
>>> nterestng
```

А в выводе требуется удалить только первую букву. И логично, что можно обратится к первому элементу через индексы:

```
value = "interesting"
value.replace(value[0], "")
print(value)
>>> nterestng
```

Не работает, так как указатель используется только чтобы вывести ту самую "i", и всё равно заменяет все "i".

Разрешается использование других функции, но хотелось бы именно с `replace()`, возможно ли это?

Comment: В таком случае , не подскажите функцию которая поможет в данной задаче?.

Comment: Если вам нужно просто убрать первый символ, то используйте срез `print(value[1:])`

Comment: @Dareten благодарю!

Comment: @Эникейщик, почему нельзя - `value.replace("i", "", 1)` ?

Comment: @MaxU i может быть и не на первом месте.

Comment: @Эникейщик, может я неправильно понял вопрос - я так понял что речь идёт о первом вхождении буквы `"i"`?

Comment: @MaxU я понял,  что нужно заменить первую букву в строке - "Нужно заменить первую букву в value"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Функция [str.replace(old, new[, count])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) принимает в качестве третьего необязательного аргумента число замен:

> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old
>   replaced by new. **If the optional argument `count` is given, only the
>   first count occurrences are replaced.**

```
In [49]: value.replace("i", "", 1)
Out[49]: 'nteresting'
```

Comment: ого! а я и не знал

Answer (score 1):

```py
s = input()
ind = s.find('i')
s = s[:ind:] + s[ind + 1::]
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так должно работать и с replace():

```
value = value.replace(value[0], "", 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value = "interesting"
print("S" + value[1:])
```

Или вот так где "S" символ на который заменяется. **Replace** Возвращает копию строки, в которой заменены **все** вхождения указанной строки указанным значением.Следовательно он не подходит.

```
value = "interesting"
if (value[:1] == 'i'):
    print("S" + value[1:])
else:
    print(value)
```